# How much of a performance hit does using println() cause?

Tags: java

I was wondering how much better for performance is using `print("... \n ...")` than`println("...")`  for printing multiple lines to the console for example with

"This is line one,

This is line two."

Method 1 is more readable however how much worse would it be for performance:

```
System.out.println("This is line one,");
System.out.println("This is line two.");
```

than Method 2:

```
System.out.print("This is line one, \n This is line two.");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "how much worse would it be for performance" you'd have to measure it to get any meaningful answer.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone had ever measured it before other wise i will

Comment: if you wrap a time around a loop that does each a million times, you can calculate the performance difference. However it may change between JVM versions and the platform you execute it on.

Comment: `System.out` is generally on the slow side of things regardless.

Comment: If you use a buffered, non-autoflushing solution like in the dupe, you get better readability than Method 1 and better performance than Method 2. In that case, it probably doesn't matter how much slower one is than the other.

Comment: The limiting factor is the console, not the code.